# Assistance locating jar containing Domino/XPages classes

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am working with a java developer who is writing a jar that needs to use multi-threading.  We discovered today that Domino is managing the way that it uses threads using the NotesThread class.  He is in the process of changing his code to do it the "domino" way. The traditional java 1.6 way is not going to work.

He is asking me for the jar that contain the following classes so he can build his solution. Can someone point me to what jar contains these classes.

```
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule;
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext;
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.SessionCloner;
```

Note: I have sent him most every XPages and ExtLib jars that I had on my machine and he is still getting a computation error.

Also, I am not 100% sure he is using NotesThread, I recently found this: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-99U64Q and sent it to him.  Perhaps all he needs is to manage the NotesContext and Session.  First I need to get him the jar he needs, hence this question. The developer does not have Notes Designer installed.  He uses Rational Application Developer to write his jar.

Comment: Note that jar files are really just zip files with some extra metadata - you should be able to locate the correct jar file with the help of an unzip utility. The problem you'll run into, of course (and it seems you may have already seen part of it), is dependencies - that one jar file may require 3 more, which may need an additional 7, which may need ...

Comment: @twalberg thanks for your comment.  There are several jars that I have on my machine that it could be in, or it could be on a server jar that I don't have access to (as a developer).  There are several IBMers who watch this tag that I hoping can answer this, including those on the XPages development team.

Comment: go for `lwpd.xsp.domino.jar` Instead of hacking JARs together, he should study [Expeditor stuff](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lewiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=Expeditor%20Toolkit)

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth That worked, thank you.  Please answer the question and I will accept.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth, if you don't mind, I am going to accept Cameron's answer. Your comment was of great help to me, but probably won't help others since it is very specific. His answer is a great tip that should help anyone trying to find which jar holds which class.  Thank you again!!

Comment: I have no problem with that, go for it :-) Cameron's answer helps to identify any class' JAR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see Frantisek has pointed you in the right direction for the jar you are looking for.
However, if you need to find one yourself here is how:

In Domino Designer, go to the Editor for Java Design Element (either open an existing .java file or create a new one, you just need to be in the Java Editor. (or alternatively switch to the 'Java' perspective)

Then press 'Ctrl + Shift + T' which is the shortcut for the 'Open Type' dialog.

The Open Type dialog lets you search for a Java Class and will open the Source if it can do so. In this case we won't be able to open the source, but it will tell us where it is getting the .class file from.

The Open Type search will show you matching classes for your search, and if you click one of the classes, it will show you the location of the class/source in the field at the bottom of the dialog.

[image: Open Type Dialog]