# XPages: how to use a fileUpload control with a bean as back-end?

Tags: file-upload, xpages, javabeans

We developed a form and fields using a backing bean. The upload used won't work, loading the page stops *after* the afterRenderResponse, for some reason:

```
<xp:fileUpload value="#{field.fileUpload}" id="fileUpload1">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="alias" value="#{form.name}.#{field.fieldName}"></xp:attr>
    </xp:this.attrs>
</xp:fileUpload>
```

The code in the bean:

```
private UploadedFile uploadedFile= null;

public FieldData(Field field) {
    this.field = field;
    this.value = field.getFieldValue();
    System.err.print("new FieldData: " + field.getFieldName());
}

public UploadedFile getFileUpload() {
    System.err.print("getFileUpload");
    return uploadedFile;
}

public void setFileUpload(UploadedFile to) {
    System.err.print("setFileUpload " + to);
    this.uploadedFile = to;
}
```

The error I keep on getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.FileuploadRendererEx.encodeEnd(FileuploadRendererEx.java:371)
at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeEnd(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:180)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:1005)
at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:857)
```

and many more lines.

Other types of fields behave nicely, except for this one. Just as an example, a text field is defined as:

```
<xp:inputText type="text" value="#{field.fieldValue}" id="inputText1">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="required" value="true" rendered="#{javascript:field.isRequired()}"></xp:attr>
        <xp:attr name="alias" value="#{form.name}.#{field.fieldName}"></xp:attr>
    </xp:this.attrs>
</xp:inputText>
```

I have beans form and field, with the necessary getter and setter functions.

The error happens somewhere in XPages, and not in my code. If I comment the upload control out, everything else works. Can someone please shed some light on why I always get a null pointer exception? Thanks!!

**EDIT** some clarifications added, especially the fact that the error occurs after the afterRenderResponse step. I print a simple trace of all events in every custom control, and there is no difference in the trace when I use the upload control or not, they are identical including the last afterRenderresponse event.

Comment: Seems your bean does not implement something the renderer needs. Look into sources of that method in stacktrace.

Comment: Probably, yes. What I forgot to mention is that the page doesn't even load the first time. The stack trace doesn't contain any of my sources. I'll check again. Maybe some "Implements" in Java is missing or so.

Comment: Is there anybody who knows what happens in FileuploadRendererEx.java on line 371??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* 370 */     Object localObject1 = getForm(paramUIComponent);
/* 371 */     String str3 = ((UIForm)localObject1).getClientId(paramFacesContext);
```

[JD-Eclipse](http://jd.benow.ca/) is very useful tool, works with Domino Designer. Works perfectly with Java [debugging](http://www.intec.co.uk/beginners-guide-to-the-java-debugger-and-tips-from-using-it-and-a-teaser/), including breakpoints.

To locate the class, use this hint: [Assistance locating jar containing Domino/XPages classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657784/assistance-locating-jar-containing-domino-xpages-classes)

My guess: file upload control misses reference to form. Possibly the component is outside the form, or the form rendering is disabled.

Comment: Ah, nice!! Certainly a useful tool! And you're right of course: I have my own <form> tag, because... well, I forgot exactly why, but I needed it somehow. So the component is definitely outside an XPages form. That doesn't seem to bother all other types of fields I use. Only the fileUpload seems to need it. So the hunt is changing, I now have to find out how to trick the fileUpload to think that there is a form, or I have to (somehow) reenable the XPages form.

Comment: I now use <xp:form> and had to make numerous modifications to make it work. Not there yet, I still have to save the file as attachment... Thanks!!